# How do I run MULTIPLE shell commands in a gruntjs task?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I currently use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to run shell commands from a [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) task. Is there a better way to run multiple commands in one task other than stringing them together with '&&'?

My Gruntfile (partial):

```
grunt.initConfig({
  shell: {
    deploy: {
      options: { stdout: true },
      command: 'mkdir -p static/styles && cp public/styles/main.css static/styles'
    }
  }
});
```

An array of commands **doesn't** work, but it would be nice:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  shell: {
    deploy: {
      options: { stdout: true },
      command: [
        'mkdir -p static/styles',
        'cp public/styles/main.css static/styles'
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can join them together:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  shell: {
    deploy: {
      options: { stdout: true },
      command: [
        'mkdir -p static/styles',
        'cp public/styles/main.css static/styles'
      ].join('&&')
    }
  }
});
```

The reason I chose not to support arrays is that some might want `;` as the separator instead of `&&`, which makes it easier to do the above.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the obvious answer is the right one :). I am not that experienced with the command line so I didn't know if using `&&` here was acceptable.

I would still support the array syntax since it's already familiar (grunt.registerTask) and thus idiomatic. Users can always `join(';')`.

Comment: Using `&&` results in it only executing the following command if the previous one succeeded. Using `;` means that it will continue executing commands regardless. I've updated the docs with an example. You're not the first asking about this :)

Comment: would be even better if the command could be run in a parallel fashion. i don't *think* the join() approach does this.

Comment: Join with one `&` instead of two and they will be run in multiple subprocesses, which happens in parallel.

Comment: @SindreSorhus Is the `;` join syntax supported on Powershell, I'm getting some strange results.